# How can I execute a line of code once in void Update?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm currently making a game in Unity. I need the player to be able to WallRun, and for a better experience, I need the camera to tilt 12.5 degrees.
This is the code that I'm using:

```
void Update()
{
    if (Physics.Raycast(transform.position, transform.right, out hitR, 1))
    {
        if (hitR.transform.tag == "Wall")
        {
            isWallR = true;
            isWallL = false;
            jumpCount += 1;
            rb.useGravity = false;
            StartCoroutine(afterRun());
            playerCamera.transform.Rotate(new Vector​3(0.0f, 0.0f, -12.5f));

        }
    }
    if (Physics.Raycast(transform.position, -transform.right, out hitL, 1))
    {
        if (hitL.transform.tag == "Wall")
        {
            isWallR = false;
            isWallL = true;
            jumpCount += 1;
            rb.useGravity = false;
            StartCoroutine(afterRun());
            playerCamera.transform.Rotate(new Vector​3(0.0f, 0.0f, -12.5f));
        }
    }
}
```

It is inside `void Update()`.
I know update is called once per frame, that makes the camera flip multiple times, but how can I call it once, so the camera only tilts the desired degrees?

Comment: Post your entire `Update` method.

Comment: You need to keep track if you executed it already. You could use an `enum` for that. `enum PlayerState { WallRunLeft, Normal, WallRunRight }` and if the playerstate is already set, you don't need to transform it again.

Comment: Use a basic state machine to divide the logic in your update method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a simple `bool` flag to stop your `Update` from being executed (or at least return immediately) until the Coroutines finish.

Also I would use an enum to differ between the sides and implement the code only once depending on the side.

Btw instead of `==` rather use `CompareTag` which is more secure and prevents silent fails for typos.

```
private enum Side
{
    Left,
    Right
}

private bool IsAfterRun;


private void Update()
{
    if(IsAfterRun) return;

    if (Physics.Raycast(transform.position, transform.right, out hitR, 1))
    {
        if (hitR.transform.CompareTag("Wall")) 
        {
            StartCoroutine(afterRun());
        }
    }
    // Additionally use else here
    // so this second Raycast is only done if the first one fails
    else if (Physics.Raycast(transform.position, -transform.right, out hitL, 1))
    {
        if (hitL.transform.CompareTag("Wall"))
        {
            StartCoroutine(afterRun(Side.Left));
        }
    }
}

private IEnumerator afterRun(Side side)
{
    // Just to be sure block concurrent routines
    if(IsAfterRun) yield break;
    IsAfterRun = true;

    isWallR = side == Side.Right;
    isWallL = side == Side.Left;
    jumpCount += 1;
    rb.useGravity = false;

    playerCamera.transform.Rotate(new Vector​3(0.0f, 0.0f, 12.5f * (side == Side.Right ? 1 : -1));

    // Your routine 
    ....


    // in the end reset your values
    rb.useGravity = false;
    playerCamera.transform.Rotate(new Vector​3(0.0f, 0.0f, 12.5f * (side == Side.Right ? -1 : 1));
    isWallR = false;
    isWallL = false;


    IsAfterRun = false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using something like this script I made:

```
using UnityEngine;

public class Test : MonoBehaviour
{
    bool start = true;

    private void Update()
    {
        if(start)
        {
            // Do your code

            start = false; // So we don't call the method again
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: And when is `start` set to true again ...?

Comment: Whenever you want. You could for example set start to true again the next time you walrun.

Comment: What mean is since you block the entire `Update` this would never detect the next wallrun  ;)

Comment: You could have an other function in update that checks for a wallrun, and if the check detecs a wallrun, make start = true